# How to mock custom hook which returns scrolled element's data with jest and enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

In my react component I am adding a css class to a div when another div get scrolled :

```
import useOnScroll from '../utils';

const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const scrollableContainerRef = useRef();
  const { scrollTop: containerScrollTop } = useOnScroll(scrollableContainerRef);

...
return (
    <div className="commonBtmSheet">
        <div data-test="btmSheet" className="OverlayWrap">
          <div data-test="btmSheet-header" className={`header ${containerScrollTop > 0 ? 'scrolled' : '' }`}>
            ...

        <div data-test="btmSheet-body" ref={scrollableContainerRef} className="OverlayOuter">
            ...
```

useOnScroll Hook:

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

function useOnScroll(ElRef) {
  const prevScrollTop = useRef();
  const [scrollData, setScrollData] = useState({});

  const handleScroll = (e) => {
    const el = e.target;

    const { scrollTop } = el;

    let direction = "down";
    if (prevScrollTop.current > scrollTop) {
      direction = "up";
    }

    setScrollData((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      scrollTop,
      direction,
    }));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const elm = ElRef.current;

    if (elm) {
      elm.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    }

    return () => {
      if (elm) {
        elm.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
      }
    };
  }, [ElRef.current]);

  return scrollData;
}

export default useOnScroll;
```

Comment: why do you want to mock a hook instead of simulating scroll with `fireEvent.scroll`? it's easy to mock hook code but it will not update so no re-rendering to your components. simulating event, in contrary, will cause re-render

Comment: @skyboyer I tried simulating the scroll event but it wasn't working.